# How to use LEFT JOIN with WHERE on three tables?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7.32 I want to retrieve all products from a product table with prices for those products from multiple shops if they are available, if they are not available NULL should be returned for the missing price at that shop.

There are three tables: products, prices, shops

Tables:

```
-- table shops
id  | name
1   | amazon
2   | ebay
3   | craigslist

-- table products
ARTICLE_ID  | name
123         | article 1
124         | article 2
125         | article 3

-- table prices
DATE    | SHOP_ID       | ARTICLE_ID    |  PRICE
201220  | 1             | 123           | 12.99
201220  | 2             | 123           | 9.99
201220  | 1             | 124           | 10.80
201221  | 1             | 123           | 13.99

-- Desired result
SHOP        | PRODUCT | PRICE
amazon      | 123     | 12.99
amazon      | 124     | 10.80
amazon      | 125     | NULL
ebay        | 123     | 9.99
ebay        | 124     | NULL
ebay        | 125     | NULL
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    p.id,
    mps.price
FROM
    shops s,
    products p
    LEFT JOIN prices mps ON p.ARTICLE_ID = mps.ARTICLE_ID AND mps.DATE = 20201220
WHERE
    s.ID IN ( '1' , '2')
```

I could not figure out how to show one line per product and shop. Is this even possible with that table setup or do I need to change my database structure?

Comment: If you create a `LEFT JOIN` for every shop, you will get everything on one line.

Comment: And please change `FROM shops s, products p ...` to  `FROM shops s INNER JOIN products p ON s.id=p.SHOP_ID ...`

Comment: Well there can be many shops, this is just a minimal example, so one JOIN per shop is not an option. The ids within the WHERE IN  statement are generated dynamically. I played around with many different SQL queries this is just one of them and I could not figure out how to solve that problem.

Comment: Don't `join` with the older comma delimited syntax. Define your `join`s with `on`s associating a relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ON` clause you must also define the link between `shops` and `prices`:

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    p.ARTICLE_ID,
    mps.price
FROM
    shops s CROSS JOIN products p
    LEFT JOIN prices mps 
    ON s.id = mps.shop_id AND p.ARTICLE_ID = mps.ARTICLE_ID  AND mps.DATE = 201220
WHERE
    s.ID IN ( '1' , '2')
ORDER BY s.name, p.ARTICLE_ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c4b6bc4c5ec7cb878b2d7410eda97c5d).
Results:

```
> name   | ARTICLE_ID | price
> :----- | ---------: | ----:
> amazon |        123 | 12.99
> amazon |        124 |  10.8
> amazon |        125 |  null
> ebay   |        123 |  9.99
> ebay   |        124 |  null
> ebay   |        125 |  null
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your help, I learned something new today, Never heared about CROSS JOIN before.

Comment: @merlin your query did a CROSS JOIN with the syntax: `FROM shops s, products p` but this is an outdated syntax. I prefer to use explicit syntax when joining. The problem with your code is that you missed to use the relation of shops and prices in the ON clause of the LEFT join.